# Vector of vectors access to undefined reference

Tags: vector, julia

I am trying to create a vector of vectors since I need the data structure to have a fixed number of rows(6) but a variable number of columns. And in each of the units of the data structure, I want to store an instance of a structure. My code is:

```
struct abc
    a::Float64
    b::Float64
    c
end


k = Vector{Vector{abc}}(6);


for i = 1:6
   for j = 1:6
        aa, bb, cc = i+1, j+1, rand(3);
        instance = abc(aa, bb, cc);
        k[i][j] = instance;
    end
end
```

I'm getting this error:

> UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
>
> Stacktrace:
>
> [1] getindex(::Array{Array{abc,1},1}, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:549
>
> [2] macro expansion at ./In[7]:5 [inlined]
>
> [3] anonymous at ./:?

Can you guys tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
k = fill(Vector{abc}(),6)
for i = 1:6
   for j = 1:6
        aa, bb, cc = i+1, j+1, rand(3)
        instance = abc(aa, bb, cc)
        push!(k[i], instance)
    end
end
```

You need to initialize first.

Comment: This code puts the same `Vector{abc}()` vector in each slot of `k`. This means that you do not have 6 different vectors but 6 times the same vector. After running the loops this single vector will have 36 elements which you can check with `length.(k)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `k` does not have its elements initialized. You can find it when you write:

```
julia> k
6-element Array{Array{abc,1},1}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
```

The simplest way to fix it is to use the following pattern:

```
julia> k = [Vector{abc}(6) for i in 1:6]
6-element Array{Array{abc,1},1}:
 abc[#undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef]
 abc[#undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef]
 abc[#undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef]
 abc[#undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef]
 abc[#undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef]
 abc[#undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef]
```

And now all works.

Notice that in Julia 0.7/1.0 you have to write `k = [Vector{abc}(undef, 6) for i in 1:6]` (with `undef`) - exactly to indicate that you are aware that you are creating an array with undefined entries. Similarly `Vector{Vector{abc}}(6)` in your original code would fail and you would have to use  `Vector{Vector{abc}}(undef, 6)` and now, I think, it is more clear that the inner arrays are not initialized.

Finally, you can do both steps in one shot using a comprehension within a comprehension like this:

```
[[abc(i+1, j+1, rand(3)) for j in 1:6] for i in 1:6]
```

Comment: Hi @Bogumil. Thanks a lot for the help!
Actually I need to have variable number of columns for each of the rows. I will be storing an instance of the structure abc in each cell of the 2D structure but in the actual problem I need to calculate the number of columns in each iteration of the outer loop(based on the value of i).
Can you please suggest what I should change.
Your solution works properly but I need to tweak it a bit for my problem I guess. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you have a function `inner_length(i)` the simplest you can do is `[[abc(i+1, j+1, rand(3)) for j in 1:inner_length(i)] for i in 1:6]`. The inner comprehension knows the value of `i` so you can use it to call the function that calculates the appropriate length using it.

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
k = Vector{Vector{abc}}(6);
```

only initialize the **outer** Vector with size 6, its components are not even vectors of zero size but simply undefined structs. 
For example:

```
julia> x=Vector{Vector{Int}}(4)

4-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
```

You can check if a component is assigned/defined (without triggering the error you mentioned in your question) using the **isassigned** function:

```
julia> isassigned(x,2)                 // <---- here

false

julia> x[2]=Vector{Int}(3);

julia> x

4-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 #undef                                                
    [140512219699984, 140512277526048, 140512217976944]
 #undef                                                
 #undef     

julia> isassigned(x,2)                 // <---- here

true
```

If you know your sizes at construction time, maybe the simplest solution is to use this:

```
k = [Vector{abc}(5) for i in 1:6]
```

This will create an (outer) vector of size 6, with all its components being a Vector{abc} of size 5

---

**update**: answering your comment.

If you want to define inner vector sizes afterward I would suggest to initialize zero sized vectors then use the **resize!** function. Code as follows:

```
struct abc end # empty struct, only for demo

k=[Vector{abc}() for i in 1:6]

for i in 1:length(k)
   resize!(k[i],rand(1:6)) # here a random size
   for j in 1:length(k[i])
      # here do what you want with k[i][j]
   end
end
```

Comment: Hi Picaud, thanks a lot for the help! Actually my data structure has variable number of columns for each row. And each cell(i.e. k[i][j] will store an instance of the structure abc). I tried this and am getting some error:
`

kk = Vector{Vector{abc}}(6);

for i = 1:6

    kk[i] = Vector{abc}(i+1);

   for j = 1:6

        aa, bb, cc = i+1, j+1, rand(3);

        instance = abc(aa, bb, cc);

        kk[i][j] = instance;

    end

end

`
I am getting:
BoundsError: attempt to access 2-element Array{abc,1} at index [3]

Any suggestions plz?

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope it fulfills your needs now :)